# How to use required field validator for DropDownCheckBoxes?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

[Drop Down CheckBoxList control](http://dropdowncheckboxes.codeplex.com/)

How to use required field validation? I only want client-side validation. When I focus out, I want to show the error message.

```
<cc2:DropDownCheckBoxes id="cblCustomerList" runat="server" width="180px">
    <style selectboxwidth="195" dropdownboxboxwidth="160" dropdownboxboxheight="195" />
    <items>
        <asp:ListItem Text = "Kidneys Donor" Value = "Kidneys Donor"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text = "Lungs Donor" Value = "Lungs Donor" >Eye Donor</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text = "Pancreas Donor" Value = "Pancreas Donor" >Blood Donor</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text = "One" Value = "1">Heart Donor</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text = "One" Value = "1" >Liver Donor</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem  >Kidneys Donor</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Lungs Donor</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Pancreas Donor</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Intestines Donor</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Cornea Donor</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Skin Donor</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Heart Valves Donor</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Tendons Donor</asp:ListItem>
    </items>
</cc2:DropDownCheckBoxes>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  the ExtendedRequiredFieldValidator control. Hope You have the DLL( DropDownCheckBoxes.dll).

```
<asp:ExtendedRequiredFieldValidator ID = "ExtendedRequiredFieldValidator1" runat = "server" ControlToValidate = "YourDropDownCheckBoxeID" ErrorMessage = "Required" ForeColor = "Red"></asp:ExtendedRequiredFieldValidator>
```